# Given an integer array nums, return true if any value appears at least twice in the array, and return false if every element is distinct. Leetcode

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates

This is one of the leetcode easy problems as stated in title. The test cases are:

Example 1:

Input: nums = [1,2,3,1]
Output: true\

Example 2:

Input: nums = [1,2,3,4]
Output: false

I have tried the following code in Java:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

class Solution {
    public static boolean containsDuplicate(int[] nums,int len) {
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<len;j++){
                if(nums[i]==nums[j]){
                   return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the size of array");
        int len=sc.nextInt();
        int [] arr=new int[len];
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
            arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }

        if(containsDuplicate(arr,len))
        {
            System.out.println("true");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("false");
        }
    }
```

I know the above is not an ideal solution but since this is my first question, the main aim is for it to at least pass all the test cases.

I am getting the following error:

```
Line 7: error: method containsDuplicate in class Solution cannot be applied to given types; [in __Driver__.java]
      boolean ret = new Solution().containsDuplicate(param_1);
                                  ^
  required: int[],int
  found:    int[]
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: It seems the error doesn't come from the code you posted, as you define no `boolean ret = ...`. Truely enough, when I dug up the leetcode assignment you mention, the method is different. Namely, you added the `int len` parameter yourself. That param is also redundant as you can find out length of array in Java without needing to remember it separately.

Answer (score 2):

Just compare the lengths of an the original array against the length of a distinctly filtered list.  And you don't need to pass the size of the array.

```
System.out.println(containsDuplicate(new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6}));
System.out.println(containsDuplicate(new int[] {1,2,3,4,6,6}));
```

prints

```
false
true
```

```
public static boolean containsDuplicate(int[] nums) {
   return Arrays.stream(nums).boxed().distinct().toList()
       .size() != nums.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code the input must look like this to solve your problem:
[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5rPU.png)

The other problem is that i and j are equal from a certain point in time. For example, if i and j are at 3, you are comparing the same numbers at nums[i] == nums[j].

An additional condition solves the problem:

```
 public static boolean containsDuplicate(int[] nums,int len) {
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<len;j++){
            if(nums[i]==nums[j] && i != j){
               return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a set.  When adding to a set, if the value doesn't exist, `set.add()` returns `true`, otherwise it returns `false`.

```
System.out.println(containsDuplicate(new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6}));
System.out.println(containsDuplicate(new int[] {1,2,3,4,6,6}));
```

prints

```
false
true
```

```
public static boolean containsDuplicate(int[] nums) {
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (!set.add(nums[i])) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```